# Merging Columns or Filling to create Multilevel headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several source files with a structure like:

[image: Source Data]

and I need to transform it to this format:

| Product | Product_code | EAN | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| myProduct1 | 000000000000016802 | 3057640444444 | 01.2022 | 1944 |
| myProduct1 | 000000000000016802 | 3057640444444 | 01.2022 | 3389 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Given my source data, I would like to know if there's a way to fill each column name with a combination of:

| 000000000000016802 EAN:3057640444444 myProduct1 01.2022 | 000000000000016802 EAN:3057640444444 myProduct1 02.2022 |
| --- | --- |
| 1369 | 1944 |
| ... | ... |

Or a more elegant solution, so I can then .melt() easily.